# Space separated file to Pandas when values have spaces

Tags: python, pandas, csv, data-cleaning, separator

I have a space separated text file. The first 3 columns include spaces *in the values*, but they have fixed width (7 characters).

Example:

```
A123456 B123456 C123456 12 158 325 0 14
D123456 E123456 F123456 1 147 23 711 0
G1 3456 H123456 F 23456 158 11 7 574 12589
J1234 6 K   456 L123456 1458 2 0.45 1 78
```

**Desired output:**

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A123456 | B123456 | C123456 | 12 | 158 | 325 | 0 |
| 1 | D123456 | E123456 | F123456 | 1 | 147 | 23 | 711 |
| 2 | G1 3456 | H123456 | F 23456 | 158 | 11 | 7 | 574 |
| 3 | J1234 6 | K 456 | L123456 | 1458 | 2 | 0.45 | 1 |

Can I read this file with pandas?

Answer (score 4):

We can use [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html#pandas-read-fwf) to "Read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame"

```
df = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', colspecs='infer', header=None)
```

`df`:

```
         0        1        2                   3
0  A123456  B123456  C123456     12 158 325 0 14
1  D123456  E123456  F123456      1 147 23 711 0
2  G1 3456  H123456  F 23456  158 11 7 574 12589
3  J1234 6  K   456  L123456    1458 2 0.45 1 78
```

---

Column `3` can be [`str.split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) on spaces if the rest of the frame is to be space separated:

```
df = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', colspecs='infer', header=None)
# Replace 3 with new columns
df = df.drop(3, axis=1).join(df[3].str.split(expand=True), rsuffix='_x')
# Rename columns
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
```

`df`:

```
         0        1        2     3    4     5    6      7
0  A123456  B123456  C123456    12  158   325    0     14
1  D123456  E123456  F123456     1  147    23  711      0
2  G1 3456  H123456  F 23456   158   11     7  574  12589
3  J1234 6  K   456  L123456  1458    2  0.45    1     78
```

`data.txt`:

```
A123456 B123456 C123456 12 158 325 0 14
D123456 E123456 F123456 1 147 23 711 0
G1 3456 H123456 F 23456 158 11 7 574 12589
J1234 6 K   456 L123456 1458 2 0.45 1 78
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I already had tried with fwf but I didn't know how to deal with the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of these: -

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt',
                   sep=";|:|,",
                   header=None,
                   engine='python')
```

Or use `read_fwf`

```
df = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', colspecs='infer', header=None)
```

This will write every value in a new column. Hope this could be helpful.